# Why cant I use c++ syntax on Node.JS terminal?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js, v8

I always wondered why I can't use C++ syntax on the Node.js terminal.

For example, V8 is a JavaScript engine that implements ECMAScript. Node.js itself is a C++ program that tells the V8 engine to use it's function. So these function are written C++ code hence this application should be able to take in C++ native syntax. Meaning if I were to type C++ code in the Node.js terminal, then the Node.js terminal should be able to pass those syntax to the C++ modules in the Node.js core and output successfully. But instead it gives a :

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
at Object.exports.createScript (vm.js:24:10)
at REPLServer.defaultEval (repl.js:236:25)
at bound (domain.js:280:14)
at REPLServer.runBound [as eval] (domain.js:293:12)
at REPLServer.<anonymous> (repl.js:441:10)
at emitOne (events.js:101:20)
at REPLServer.emit (events.js:188:7)
at REPLServer.Interface._onLine (readline.js:224:10)
at REPLServer.Interface._line (readline.js:566:8)
at REPLServer.Interface._ttyWrite (readline.js:843:14)
```

I am just looking for a clear explanation how the two languages are abstracted although Node.js is written on top of C++.

Comment: It's not unusual at all for a compiler or interpreter for one language to be written in a different language. In fact it's a necessity for at least the first version of that language's compiler. This doesn't make it able to compile or interpret they language they used automatically, any more than having a text editor written in C++ would give it that capability. *Could* they build a C++ compiler into NodeJS? Sure, but that has nothing to do with it being *written* in C++.

Comment: ...that said, there are projects that will let you take C++ and compile it into a form of JavaScript that will run it in supported implementations at very high performance. http://kripken.github.io/emscripten-site/

Comment: As an ugly analogy, digestive waste is made from food, but it does not mean you would ingest it...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.No idea why someone would down vote a question which I required an explanation from an expert as I didnt know the relationship the C++ ,v8 and node had. Cheers

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just because a program is written in C++, doesn't mean it can interpret C++ code. Would you expect this program to understand C++ code when you run it?

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        std::cout << line << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Node and V8 are written in C++ but their job is to interpret Javascript code. They won't run any C++ code, the same way a C++ compiler won't compile any Javascript code.